# jQuery html() and &amp;

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm doing a search within list of people. And I want it to show results on the fly and so it does. But there is one link that I need and it should look like this:

```
chatid=18&userid=45&create=new
```

but after the results are displayed through this:

```
$.get('/ajax.php', {sec: 'search_users', ajax: 1, search_for: $(this).val()}, function(data)
{
    $(".rBoxContentStaff").html(data);
});
```

I get this result:

```
chatid=18&amp;userid=45&amp;create=new
```

And the link doesn't work. This seems to happen in html() and also append().

**I found no solution for this so I had to change the triggering of the link.**

Comment: What kind of element is that ".rBoxContentStaff" ?

Comment: That doesn't matter inakiabt, html special chars when requested by ajax, don't get interpreted by the browser .. that's why the links came out that way

Comment: did you try to return a json array with the IDs and join them with an &?

Comment: have you tried my new solution yet? I tested it and the link path is set correctly and takes you to the page as expected

Comment: it does not happen in .attr("href") though. Have you tried it? I tested the others and I see what you are saying when you alert it afterwards it is &amp; but when you alert .attr("href") it says & as it should and the link will redirect you as it should when clicked

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Ampersands _should_ be escaped in links (although browsers are tolerant of unescaped ampersands).

Answer (score 2):

You said you are trying to set the link path correct?
If so try this

```
$(".rBoxContentStaff").attr("href", data);
```

the `.html()` is changing the & to an html & (`&amp;`) but using `.attr("href")` sets the link path and it works with &s as well

Comment: that I know I'm looking for the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this:

```
$(".rBoxContentStaff").html(data); });
```

Try this:

```
$(".rBoxContentStaff").append(data); });
```

[text()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) escapes html characters ... I can't find anything about [html()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) escaping characters (and indeed, its documentation seems to indicate otherwise.
However, after testing with alert at jmein's suggestion, it does encode special characters.  Append() does not do so.

Comment: I dont think this is the issue. If he alerts the data before he puts it into .html() it displays as & but if he alerts the .html() after putting it in displays as &amp;

Comment: @jmein - that's why I suggest specifying "text" in his get command, since, as he said, he's not url or html encoding his ajax data.

Comment: Its not what he is returning thats not working (or at least it does not sound like it). It is when he is setting the link path using the .html()

Comment: Try to put an & into a link using .html(). It displays the & as &amp; when you alert the .html() afterward. If you set the link path using .attr("href") however it will alert it properly afterward. Therefore, the link would work properly.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, but append seems to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

html special chars when requested by ajax, don't get interpreted by the browser .. that's why the links came out that way. One thing you can do is a sstring replace in javascript:

```
data = str.replace(/&amp;/, "&");
```

Comment: data returns everything right if I alert it, this happens after html() it seems.

Comment: Then don't return the full link, return it as a json array, for example

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the $.ajax() function instead of $.get().

With $.ajax() you can specify your datatype yourself (and use other options).

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/ajax.php",
data: "sec=search_users&ajax=1&search_for="+$(this).val(),
cache: false,
dataType: "html",
success: function(html){
    $(".rBoxContentStaff").html(html);
} });
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I took a look at what happens in html(). It seems that this is the work of innerHTML that changes the & to &amp;

Comment: If html() is the problem then wouldnt $("#test").html("test&test"); also display test&amp;test?
I still think you're returning XML data instead of plaintext.

Comment: the issue is that when you put an & in through .html it displays as an & as it should but the actual value is &amp; as you would see when you clicked the link or if you alerted the .html() after placing the & within it

Answer (score 0):

And there's also the way to convert getting just the text (the `<a />` is just a helper):

```
$('<a /'>).html(data).text()
```

This will move `&amp;` to `&`, and also all other special characters like `&imp;` etc...