# Jquery .attr converts & to &amp; in my links !

Tags: jquery

Am forced to use jquery and am not familiar with it .

Anyway , i store a link in a span `<span id="link">http://x.com?x=1&x=2</span>`

when looking up through the js file that gets that variable and puts it in `href` of a link using this code `$j("#sn_title").attr('href', news_link.html());` , the `&` in the link is converted to `&amp;` .

Any clues ?

Comment: "forced to use jquery" Oh, my...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&amp;` is actually acceptable (and preferred) for links per the HTML spec.

However, if you want to make it not change what you have in news_link, you should be doing: `$j("#sn_title").attr('href', news_link.text());`

Notice the use of `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: The `attr` method takes a value, not escaped source.  `&amp;` is not acceptable here.

Answer (score 2):

The `html()` method returns the actual HTML of the element.

`&` is a special character in HTML (it's used for entities) and cannot appear as a normal character.
Your HTML is invalid (`&x` is not an entity), but the browser automatically corrects it to `&amp;` as it is parsed.
jQuery faithfully returns the fixed-up HTML when you ask it to.

If you want the *text* of the element, call `.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

The .html() is changing the & to an html & (&) but using .attr("href") sets the link path .

Please see this link
[jQuery html() and &amp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400332/jquery-html-and-amp)