# How to get selected option value of dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using dropdown and I want to get value of selected option.

I am able to do that using jquery html() method.

But in case selected option value is containing html encodable character lets say it is &(ampersand.)

```js
alert('html() : ' + $('#dropdown option:selected').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
<option selected>Test & Get knowledge</option>
</select>
```

Then this & is encoded to &a m p;

How to treat this value as only text?

Comment: You can use, .text() in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/programtheweba/8gohx47g/

By using Jquery text(), we will get only text and characters are not encoded.

```js
alert('text() : ' +$('#dropdown').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
<option selected>Test & Get knowledge</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Really? You the one who asked the question. Even though there are multiple right answers, only your answer has got the upvote. Really great!!

Comment: I cant upvote my que/ans. so yes I am also surprised!

Answer (score 1):

> `&` is a special character in HTML (it's used for entities) and cannot appear as a normal character.
>   Your HTML is invalid (`&x` is not an entity), but the browser automatically corrects it to `&amp;` as it is parsed.
>   jQuery faithfully returns the fixed-up HTML when you ask it to.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145753/1719752)**

Hence use `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
$('#dropdown option:selected').text();
```

You can also use `.val()` along with select element selector to get selected options text value:

```
 $('#dropdown').val();
```

Comment: Hey man. did you see OP's answer? Something is messing up here.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: what is messing up??

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: we cant do anything other than flagging it for moderation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead:

```js
console.log('text() : ' + $('#dropdown option:selected').text());//prints out text() : Test & Get knowledge
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option selected>Test & Get knowledge</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
$('#dropdown option:selected').text();
```

Or use `.val()`

```
$('#dropdown').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Include `jQuery` in your code.
2. Wrap your code in DOM Ready `$(function(){ ... })`
3. Use `$('#dropdown option:selected').val()` to fetch the value.

```js
$(function(){
alert('html() : ' + $('#dropdown option:selected').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
<option selected>Test & Get knowledge</option>
</select>
```

`&` will be parsed as `&` only and will not be changed.